# I can't run a scene in unity 2022

Tags: unity-game-engine

After I start the scene, the following error is displayed

`Fatal Error! Overflow in memory allocator. UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderPipelineManager:DoRenderLoop_Internal (UnityEngine.Rendering.RenderPipelineAsset,intptr,UnityEngine.Object,Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.AtomicSafetyHandle)`

I tried to find it on the Internet, but nothing helped

UPD: If I remove the following script, then everything works. But I need to keep it

```
public class SaveLoadManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    public Transform player;
    private string userName;

    private float X;
    private float Y;
    private float Z;

    private float pos_x;
    private float pos_y;
    private float pos_z;

    private void Awake()
    {
        userName = PlayerPrefs.GetString("txt");
        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;

        LoadData();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(StartSaving());
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        pos_x = player.position.x;
        pos_y = player.position.y;
        pos_z = player.position.z;
    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SavePlayerPosition());
    }

    public void LoadData()
    {
        StartCoroutine(LoadPlayerPositionX());
        StartCoroutine(LoadPlayerPositionY());
        StartCoroutine(LoadPlayerPositionZ());
    }

    IEnumerator SavePlayerPosition()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var DBTask_0 = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").Child("position_x").SetValueAsync(pos_x);
            var DBTask_1 = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").Child("position_y").SetValueAsync(pos_y);
            var DBTask_2 = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").Child("position_z").SetValueAsync(pos_z);

            yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask_0.IsCompleted);

            if (DBTask_0.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask_0.Exception}");
            }

            yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask_1.IsCompleted);

            if (DBTask_1.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask_1.Exception}");
            }

            yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask_2.IsCompleted);

            if (DBTask_2.Exception != null)
            {
                Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask_2.Exception}");
            }
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadPlayerPositionX()
    {
        var DBTask = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            DataSnapshot dataSnapshot = DBTask.Result;
            X = float.Parse(dataSnapshot.Child("position_x").Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadPlayerPositionY()
    {
        var DBTask = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
            Y = float.Parse(snapshot.Child("position_y").Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator LoadPlayerPositionZ()
    {
        var DBTask = databaseReference.Child("users").Child(userName).Child("GameData").GetValueAsync();

        yield return new WaitUntil(predicate: () => DBTask.IsCompleted);

        if (DBTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(message: $"Failed to register task with {DBTask.Exception}");
        }
        else
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = DBTask.Result;
            Z = float.Parse(snapshot.Child("position_z").Value.ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator StartSaving()
    {
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.3f);
        //player.position = new Vector3(X, Y, Z);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        SaveData();
    }
}
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////help me///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: might be 1 of two memory issues, your pc doesn't have enough RAM or your gpu doesnt have enough ram

Comment: see -> https://community.gamedev.tv/t/overflow-in-memory-allocator-particle-system/126308

Comment: it doesn't help

Comment: Is that in the ide? What happens if you use the profiler? Can you slowly add back bits and see where the memory jump is? Or use the log files to see how much its trying to allocate. There was a guy on the unity forums who's scene tried to load 160gb of memory.